# What formula to use in Cell A2, so it can automatically insert date from top to bottom

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

What formula to use in Cell A2, so it can automatically insert date from top to bottom

I want A2 always show the latest date.

For example,
Today's is 7/30/2021.  The following column will show 7/29/2021, 7/28/2021, 7/27/2021 .....

Let's say we entered the second day (tomorrow).
I want A2 show 7/31/2021, he following column will show 7/30/2021, 7/29/2021, 7/28/2021 .....

Thank you so much for your help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Pva3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to populate the whole column :

```
=arrayformula(TODAY()+2-ROW(A2:A))
```

replace today() as necessary

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```js
=TODAY()+2-ROW()
```

This will show dates starting today and going back in time.

See on [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p1ufoME_skalg1GB5CID2X7lParkPCRmWPya7KV-mHw/edit?usp=sharing)